# error with Android Studio download

Tags: android

so when I was downloading Android Studio it would not download properly cause it says "The environment variable JAVA_HOME(with the values of c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp)does not point to a valid JYM installition" , why does it say that and what should I do to fix that and get the android studio working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the JAVA_HOME variable in your path settings. Make sure you have downloaded a JDK. Info on how to set your path variable can be found at here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html